# Batch File - Collapse all file from multiple folder and rename according to the folder name

Tags: batch-file, directory, batch-rename

I have files in multiple folder, i received all these files monthly and i need to copy all files into one folder with this naming convention YYYYMMDD.csv

```
Current Folder <CRLF>
YYYY\MM\D\ir\external_report.csv

2015\03\1\ir\external_report.csv
2015\03\2\ir\external_report.csv
.
.
.
2015\03\31\ir\external_report.csv
```

Need to be in this folder

```
2015\03\20150301.csv
.
.
2015\03\20150331.csv
```

Comment: Post the code you have tried and any messages or errors you receive.

Comment: Need some clarification: _the only_ **file** `external_report.csv` in each `YYYY\MM\D\ir\ ` **folder**  or   _multiple files_ in  `YYYY\MM\D\ir\external_report.csv` _folder_?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, this may be of use:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion


for /r C:\2015 %%i in (*.csv) do (
    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=\ " %%j in ('echo %%~pi') do (
    if %%l lss 10 (
    move "%%i" "c:\%%j\%%k\%%j%%k0%%l%%~xi"
    ) else (
    move "%%i" "c:\%%j\%%k\%%j%%k%%l%%~xi"
    )
    )
)
pause
```

It should put all the `.csv` files in the relevant month folder, within the parent year folder, along with renaming them per your naming convention. You may need to change the directory/path to suit yours.

Comment: You are assuming that the year folder hangs off the root. This will not work if the year is a subfolder of another folder.

Comment: No, but with a few adjustments it should, the template is there... right?

Comment: Only if you know exactly how deep the year is within the folder hierarchy. The code would have to change every time the level changed.

Comment: I agree. I hope the asker doesn't mind doing that :P :)

Answer (score 0):

The following will move and rename all `external_report.csv` files below the current folder that reside within a `YYYY\MM\D\ir\` folder hierarchy. It will not move `external_report.csv` files that are not within the template hierarchy. The `YYYY` folder can be at any depth within your current folder hierarchy. This will also delete the `D\ir` folders if they are empty after the MOVE.

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /s /a-d external_report.csv^|findstr /i "[\\][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][\\][01][0-9][\\][0-9][0-9]*[\\]ir[\\]external_report.csv$"'
) do for %%D in (
  "%%F\..\.."
) do for %%M in (
  "%%F\..\..\.."
) do for %%Y in (
  "%%F\..\..\..\.."
) do (
  if %%~nD lss 10 (
    move "%%F" "%%~dpD%%~nY%%~nM0%%~nD.csv
  ) else (
    move "%%F" "%%~dpD%%~nY%%~nM%%~nD.csv
  )
  %= The following will delete the day\ir   =%
  %= folders if and only if they are empty  =%
  2>nul (rd "%%F\.." && rd "%%F\..\..")
)
```

How it works.

- The `DIR /B /S` command lists the full path to all `external_report.csv` files.
- The result is piped to `FINDSTR` with a regular expression that validates the file is in a `YYYY\MM\D\ir` folder. It is not a perfect validation, but it should be more than adequate.
- `FOR /F` iterates the result in a loop.
- Each of the date components is extracted by using an additional `FOR` loop with the `\..` trick to walk up the hierarchy one level, and the `~n` modifier to get the resultant base name (the year, month, or day)
- The `%= xxxxxxx =%` is a safe way to embed a comment within a loop. In reality, it is expansion of a non-existent variable, which amounts to nothing. The variable cannot exist because variable names cannot contain `=`.

The rest is straight-forward

Comment: NIce **definitive** solution! I like the `findstr`, `regex`, `\..` approach to mitigating folder "depth". I have learnt by this thanks... If I may ask an off-topic question, have you ever played South American pan pipes (pan flute)? - For all my labial gymnastics I can never produce a decent sound. :P

Comment: @Chris - Man, I can't play those things for my life! I can hold a note for 1 minute on one breath on the Native American (North American) flute, but I play the pan pipes for 30 seconds (breathing as needed) and I'm dizzy and ready to pass out. Check out my [YouTube Channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/dfbenham/videos) or [SoundCloud profile](http://soundcloud.com/dave-benham) for examples of my flute music.

Comment: Brilliant, relaxing, original material... I've always loved wind instruments, alas the recorder is the extent of my wind instrument repertoire... I grew up with tracks like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSwu8-ohoWs) from my motherland.